# Unable to compile a C++ class using code blocks

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Everytime I try to compile a class in c++ I get this error:

> ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|

Here is the code for my Classes class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Cat cat1;
    cat1.speak();
    cat1.jump();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for my header Cat.h:

```
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

class Cat {
public:
    void speak();
    void jump();
};

#endif /* CAT_H_ */
```

And here is the code for my Cat Class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

void Cat::speak() {
     cout << "Meouwww!!!" << endl;
}

void Cat::jump() {
    cout << "Jumping to top of bookcase" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should learn a bit about the IDE you're using, or run some tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

This error have nothing to do with your code. It's a problem related to your environnement. There is 2 commun mistake that will lead to this:

There is no compiler associated with your IDE so try to install one. Or you should Download codeBlocks with mingw compiler integrated

You didn't create a project So try creating a project and then add this files.

I hope that I answered your question.

Comment: How do I create a project in codeblocks? I have tried to create one but  failed multiple times and I have experienced permanent agonizing pain

Comment: try watching this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1kubuz1loI
go directly to 1:57 if you want

Comment: I created the project  , then I added all of the files to the folder of the project and I am still getting the same error when I attempt to compile it. So complicated

Comment: Am I required to install mingw in order for a class file to compile?

Comment: I did not install mingw when I initially installed codeblocks

Comment: yes you have to install a compiler with codeBlocks  there is many compiler for c++ but the default one uses with codeblocks is mingw.   So try uninstall codeblocks and install this version https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks/Binaries/16.01/Windows/codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe

this is the best way you don't need any configuration.

Comment: if you don't trust the link I gave you, you can chose the version by your self. So select codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe from this page
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26